# In a website, how to make two segments of users follow the desired path

Tags: website-design, usability, interaction-design, navigation, users

I was asked to design a website for a company that has two different segments: B2C (business to customers) and B2B (business 2 business)...
The company says both segments are equally important.

How do you make a website mirror this and make the right clients go to the right path?

Answer (score 3):

Adding a destinct **Private - Professional** selector at the top is done on [telenor.se](http://www.telenor.se/privat/index.html). Maybe that would do the tric

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fURNba.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You should have a simple selector (as Benny suggested) to change between the consumer and business sites.  However, I would also present a users with a dialogue on their first visit asking them which site they would like to see.  From then on, I would default to that website for them (using cookies).  Something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A dropdown is clear and informative and saving space
[image]